# Can't Decrypt password from Login Data Chrome

Tags: c++, aes-gcm

```
`std::string decrypt_password(const std::string& ciphertext, const std::string& secret_key) {
    try {
        if (ciphertext.size() < 31) {
            std::cout << "[ERR] Invalid ciphertext format." << std::endl;
            return "";
        }

        // Initialization vector for AES decryption
        std::vector<byte> initialization_vector(ciphertext.begin() + 3, ciphertext.begin() + 15);

        // Get encrypted password by removing suffix bytes (last 16 bytes)
        std::vector<byte> encrypted_password(ciphertext.begin() + 15, ciphertext.end() - 16);

        // Build the cipher to decrypt the ciphertext
        GCM<AES>::Decryption gcmDecryption;
        gcmDecryption.SetKeyWithIV(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(secret_key.data()), CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, initialization_vector.data(), initialization_vector.size());

        // Create a buffer to hold the decrypted password
        std::string decrypted_password;
        decrypted_password.resize(encrypted_password.size()); // Resize the buffer to the correct size

        // Decrypt the password
        CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter adf(gcmDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decrypted_password));
        adf.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(encrypted_password.data()), encrypted_password.size());
        adf.MessageEnd();


        // Check if the authentication was successful
        if (!adf.GetLastResult()) {
            std::cout << "[ERR] Authentication failed. Unable to decrypt the password." << std::endl;
            return "";
        }

        // Return the decrypted password
        return decrypted_password;
    }
    catch (const Exception& e) {
        std::cout << "[ERR] " << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[ERR] Unable to decrypt, Chrome version <80 not supported. Please check." << std::endl;
        return "";
    }
}`
```

I tryed it to decrypt my pass from google chrome (education purposes) but i doesnt work for me, Im use crypto++ lib for c++. 'cipher = generate_cipher(secret_key, initialisation_vector)  decrypted_pass = decrypt_payload(cipher, encrypted_password) decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass.decode() there is for Python pycryptodome lib'`

Comment: Without knowing the key used to encrypt the password, I don't believe it is possible to decrypt the password.  That is kinda the whole purpose of encrypting passwords in the first place.  Typically, if you want to validate a users entered password, you use the same encryption algorithm to encrypt the entered password and compare the result against the saved encryptd password.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the password was encrypted at all. It was almost certainly hashed, in which case you can't decrypt it at all.